# There is some way for read a substate in reducers with react and redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My store is the next:

```
const initialState = {
    all: {
        "name": "",
        "datas": {
            "data1": {
                "subdata1": [],
                "subdata2": [],
            },
            "data2": {
                "subdata1": [],
                "subdata2": [],
            },
        }
    }
}
```

I have the next Components:

```
* All: main Component, map to Data with all.datas
* Data: show data1 or data2 or data3. map to Subdata with data1 and data2 ...
* Subdata: show list subdata1
```

I have a redux connect in Subdata, and I want that the reducers, instead of return general state, return a subdata state.

For example:

Subdata.js:

```
class Subdata extends React.Component {
    // ....
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        subdata: ownProps.subdata
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return { actions: bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch) }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Subdata);
```

reducers.js:

```
const subdata = (state = {}, action) => {
    // I want that state return: subdata, in this case, []
    // instead of all: {...}
    const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));

    switch(action.type) {
        case "ADD_SUBDATA":
            // In this moment: I need pass a lot of vars: data_id and subdata_id
            my_subdata = state.datas[data_id][subdata_id]
            // I want get directly the subdata
            my_subdata = state.subdata
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Is this possible? How?

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You could consider using `dot-prop-immutable` or [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) in your reducer to selectively operate on a  "slice" of your store.

Pseudo code using dotProp example:

```
// Getter 
dotProp.get({foo: {bar: 'unicorn'}}, 'foo.bar')
```

Signature:

```
get(object, path) --> value
```

I notice in your code you are using the following to "clone" your state:

```
const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
```

This is not optimal as you are cloning completely all your state object, when instead you should operate only on a part of it (where the reducer operates, specially if you are working with combined reducers).